# Remove RxJava unchecked cast on combineLatest warning without suppressing them

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

I created a method that make multiple calls with retrofit and return a list of products using the combineLatest rxjava operator, then i use map function to get only the parsed response bodies.

The method works as expected but i got 2 warnings of Unchecked Casts on Android Studio.

```
Unchecked cast: Any! to Response<Product>
```

and

```
Unchecked cast: List<Product?> to List<Product>
```

What is the right way to get rid of these 2 unchecked cast warnings? I've tried several ways to 
solve this but with no luck.

My method is something like this:

```
    private fun getProductList(): Observable<List<Product>> {
        val retrofitApiCalls = listOf(
            Observable.just(
                Response.success(
                    Product("Potato")
                )
            ),
            Observable.just(
                Response.success(
                    Product("Banana")
                )
            )
        )

        return Observable.combineLatest(retrofitApiCalls) {
            return@combineLatest it.map { response -> (response as Response<Product>).body() } as List<Product>
        }
    }
```

[Android Studio Unchecked cast error print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hb5C.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
 return@combineLatest it.filter { it is Response<Product> }
                        .map { it.body() }.toList<Product>()
```

It will already be auto cast to `List<Product>`

Comment: This doesn't work. But thanks! You gave me the idea to fix this List cast with:

`return@combineLatest it.mapNotNull { response -> (response as Response<Product>).body() }`

but still having one last warning: **Unchecked cast: Any! to Response<Product>**

this one i don't have any ideas

Comment: now does not compile with this message: `Cannot check for instance of erased type Response<Product>`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your code simplifies down to

```
private fun getProductList(): Observable<List<Product>> = 
    Observable.just(
        listOf(
            Product("Potato"),
            Product("Banana")
        )
    )
```

If that is not the case, your provided sample code is incomplete.

Comment: I explained in the description what my method does. This part is just to illustrate that in that place i make normal retrofit calls that returns `Observable<Response<Product>>`. I even named the variable retrofitCalls to indicate that. But sorry if was not enough. I will try edit the example later.